# Route controllers with different actions to one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

For the sake of discussion, let's say I have two controllers: Alpha and Beta. And, let's say, I want to map them to the same action, but on one or a different controller: /Alpha/DoThis & /Beta/DoThis get sent to either /Alpha/DoThis or even /Omega/DoThis. How might one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` would be my guess (or `Application_Start` if you don't have one):

```
// just in case you need the alias
//var routes = RouteCollection.Routes;

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RedirectSomeRoutes",
    url: "{originalController}/DoThis",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Alpha", // Use this controller
        action = "DoThis",    // And use this action
    },
    // Setup constraints so it only runs against the supplied
    // matching controllers (e.g. Alpha, Beta and Omega)
    constraints: new {
        originalController = "^Alpha|Beta|Omega$"
    }
);
```

Note that MVC runs with the first match within the RouteTable, so you want the most specific route listed first, and the most generic (usually `{controller}/{action}/{id}`) listed last.

Alternatively, you could use rewrites (within your `web.config`) which would give you more power in terms of response codes, etc (e.g. 403 redirect).

Comment: And if I wanted to match any controller? I assume I'd need to modify originalController with the regular expression for any? I.e. ".*"?

Comment: Just remove the `constraint` parameter from `MapRoute` (the default constraint is similar to that of `.*`).